# Dropdown menu for big list of items in Angular

Tags: angular

I need to create a dropdown menu with a lot of items I get from a server endpoint, and when I click in each item of the menu, I need to show some data related to that item (but coming from another endpoint).

I have already used `*ngFor` to display all the items in the dropdown, but have no idea on how to link each of them so that the other data is shown.

Plus from what I understood, I can't use `href` or `[routerLink]`, because `href` will reload the entire page, while with `[routerLink]` I would need to create a new `Component` for each item, which is ridiculous.

Am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: If you are using angular and material, I recommend looking at the example in the docs

https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

Answer (score 0):

Margherita, yes you're missing something

Thre're two aproach

1.-[Using routing](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Imagine a routing like

```
const routes: Routes = [{path:"detail/:name",component:DetailComponent}];
```

Your app.component use an array of menus

```
  menus=[{label:"one",data:1},{label:"two",data:2}]
```

And show it in the .html

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus">
   <a [routerLink]="'detail/'+menu.data>{{menu.label}}</a>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And your detailComponent, subscribe in ngOnInit to ActiveRouter [see the docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.name = params['name'];
  });
}
```

2.-Using [component interaccion](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Then you add a new variable in your app.component

```
data:any
```

And your app.component like

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus">
   <button (click)="data=menu.data">{{menu.label}}</button>
</div>
<app-detail [data]="data"></app-detail>
```

In this case [intercept the value of data](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter), so your detail component has an `@Input`

```
@Input() set data(value){
   this.name=value
}
```